# Guardar request en node.js

Tags: nodejs, post, http, requests, async

Tengo una función con el siguiente código:

```javascript
function post(url, data) {

}
```

y quiero que al ejecutarla mande una solicitud `HTTP POST` a la `url` con los datos de `data`. Buscando en la documentación de [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) he estado buscando como hacerlo pero no he encontrado nada. He probado a usar:

```javascript
const post = async (url, data) => {
    return await request.post({url: url, formData: data});
}
```

pero tampoco funciona. Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

**EDICIÓN: **no tiene porque ser específicamente con `request`, si hay otro modulo que funcione me sirve

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con `request`?. Ese paquete ha sido marcado como *deprecated*, es decir que se desaconseja su uso. Saludos

Comment: me sirve cualquiera, usaba request porque lo conocía mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con node-fetch podrias hacerlo de esta manera por ejemplo, aunque tiene muchas mas opciones:

```js
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

const post = async(url, data)=>{
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {}, //si fueran necesarios los headers..
            body : data  
        }).then((response)=>{
            //manejar la respuesta
            return response //devolver lo que necesites
        }).catch(err=>{
          //manejar posibles errores
        });
}
```

te puede interesar echarle un ojo a la libreria [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó!